# Signup procedure: Activation mails templates guidelines?

Tags: registration

I'm finishing up a signup form and I am wondering if there's any rules / guidelines to the activation mails the system sends out ?

Is there also an activation template I can review online to get a better idea?

Comment: This question will get higher quality answers if you expand upon your use case, show some examples of prior research you have done, and narrow the scope of your question to be less broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the activation email free of graphics, as users quickly want to click on the activation link and already interested in your product. Give them a link to click on, and an additional url that they can copy and paste into a web browser if the link doesn't work.

### **[Click here to activate your account  →](http://example.com)**

Its always a good idea to give the users a visual cue. Also include your support email/ phone to sort out any activation issues.